# Update error in my Products table after creating AFTER UPDATE trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I had inserted a simple Procedure (_ControlProduct) and it is working fine in SQL
I am calling it from the AFTER UPDATE trigger in Products Table but then I am having this error

> ERROR 1109: 1109: Unknown table 'Products' in field list

SQL Statement:

```
UPDATE `lakcom_NewDB`.`Products` 
   SET `SuppCat_id` = '2' 
 WHERE (`Product_id` = '43')
```

my trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `lakcom_NewDB`.`Products_AFTER_UPDATE` 
    AFTER UPDATE ON `Products` 
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            call _controlproduct(Products.Product_id);
        END
```

my _ControlProduct is:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `_ControlProduct`(Product int)
BEGIN
update Basket 
    set Basket.ToControl = 1 
where Basket.Product_id=Product 
and Basket.id<>0;
END
```

Comment: Not that I think it's actually the cause of the problem, because MySQL complains about an UPDATE that you dind't actually post, but when you say `Products.Product_id` in `_controlproduct(Products.Product_id);` what do you think MYSQL will understand it to mean? If you're trying to refer to rows that have been updated, you either use OLD or NEW pseudotables. Products.product_id is a column, which is relatively meaningless in the context

Comment: There doesn't seem much point calling a procedure from a trigger ,  why do think this is a sensible thing to do I wonder.

Comment: according to my understanding the trigger will work only for records that have been actually updated. I want to call my procedure whenever any record is updated and this is why I am getting the id field to use it as parameter to update a relevant record in y basket table

Comment: 'according to my understanding the trigger will work only for records that have been actually updated' not quite FOR EACH ROW will be processed but basket could be updated for as many rows in basket meet the conditions described in your procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to your code attempt

```
CREATE TRIGGER `lakcom_NewDB`.`Products_AFTER_UPDATE` 
    AFTER UPDATE ON `Products` 
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            update Basket 
              set Basket.ToControl = 1 
              where Basket.Product_id=new.product_id 
              and Basket.id<>0;
        END
```

Sample data and expected outcome would be helpful(to you)